# Is there a way to recognize destructible environment in XCOM:Enemy Unknown?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Just so I know where not to hide my Heavy soldier behind.

Comment: X-Com is pretty much known for its destructable environment.  With enough explosives, you can level pretty much any map.

Comment: @Zibbobz That may have been the case in [tag:xcom-ufo-defense], but unfortunately the relaunch a) made some objects (e.g. car wrecks) unremovable and b) basically does not give you enough ammunition to _actually_ destroy everything...

Comment: So you can't level an entire hill now?  Sad. :(

Answer (score 5):

I'm almost sorry to have to tell you this, but by and large there's no such thing as a non-destructible environment; by and large if you can take cover behind it and it isn't actual ground, it can be destroyed -- and in fact, most aliens that carry grenades *love* lobbing them at enemies in cover.

The only real exception to this seems to be car wrecks -- after a car explodes, the wreck can't be blown up a second time and I think it'll keep providing what little cover it does for the rest of the encounter...

Comment: There are some objects that can't be destroyed, some that are visually reduced but keep their full-cover status, and also some objects that change from full to half cover but never vanish totally.

Comment: There are plenty of indestructible cover spots. Terrain (not rocks and trees) in UFO maps, some of the big truck cabs, those big yellow construction vehicles, some of the ramps (others aren't cover), the goo-spewer things in abduction maps, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

You'll simply have to learn through experience which objects can be destroyed, which ones can get damaged but not ever fully removed, and which objects explode when shot.

I'd primarily worry about the last category, which is primarily made up of cars and tractors.

Generally speaking, if it doesn't disintegrate after being hit by a rocket, you're not going to lose your cover due to terrain destruction.

Comment: Cars and tractors at least give you a turn of "hey, I'm on fire, you probably ought to move." The one that gets me every time is the gas pumps on the gas station map. Those suckers are just Made Of Explodium, and they go up instantly on being shot.

Comment: Oh, right. Wrecked cars are indestructible, I think -- after they've exploded they can't explode again.

Comment: I've started a list of which types of scenery can be destroyed to which extent over at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136179/in-xcom-enemy-unknown-which-types-of-scenery-are-destructible/136180#136180. I hope that's an appropriate community wiki entry... assuming so, (and hence it doesn't get removed), please do add to the list!