# In XCOM: Enemy Unknown, which types of scenery are destructible?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Inspired by [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136171/is-there-a-way-to-recognize-destructible-environment-in-xcomenemy-unknown), I thought it would be helpful to have a list of the scenery types that can and cannot be destroyed by weapons fire, grenades, etc.

Comment: Please don't dispute closures in the question; either take it up on Meta, or leave a comment on it.

Comment: @fbueckert Um... the message that it has been closed/marked as dupe actually says "If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different". I followed the instructions.

Comment: @fbueckert But as you have requested, the dispute is that this is not a duplicate. The linked question is "Is there a way to recognise destructible environment", to which people have already correctly answered "no". This question is "*Which* types of environment are destructible". I agree that they are similar, and would have suggested that the first be edited to the second, had it not already been answered.

Comment: You must be reading something different than me, as what I see says, "If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question."  But, yeah, I agree it's somewhat confusing.  We like to ensure questions and answers are free of information that has nothing to do with the actual question or answer.  That's why we prefer it in comments.  As for whether or not these are duplicates, I can see why people think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @fbueckert The full text of what I am seeing reads "
marked as duplicate by cloudymusic, kalina, Billy Mailman, Raven Dreamer♦ 4 hours ago

This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question." If that is not how things should be handled, then that text really needs to be changed.

Comment: What it means by edit the question isn't to go, "Hey, this is different, here's how", it's meant to be used to edit the question to clarify and bring to the front the difference.  Focus on editing it to make the difference much clearer.  If you can do that, you might get the reopen votes you need for it.  But if you reword it to focus on the problem, it does honestly sound like it's a dupe, because the problem is figuring out what can and can't be destroyed.

Comment: *shrug* Please don't take this as a personal attack, it isn't, but the last two times I've tried to contribute to this site: The first time some mods edited my question to ask something totally different; This time something is marked as a dupe when it isn't, and any recourse that there is, if it does exist, is very confusing. I think I shall give up contributing and go back to just searching for answers when I want to know things :-(

Answer (score 5):

This list is incomplete. Please add to it! (hence the community wiki flag. I hope I have used this correctly)

## Scenery that explodes without warning when hit

- Petrol pumps
- Alien power cores

## Scenery that explodes one turn after it is hit

- Cars / trucks

## Scenery that can be destroyed by weapons (leaving no cover)

- Most walls
- Construction site toilet cubicles
- Most gravestones

## Scenery that can be partially destroyed by weapons (cover goes from full to half)

## Scenery that cannot be destroyed

- The alien "pods" that are seen part-embedded in the ground
- Cars & trucks that have already exploded
- Closed truck trailers and rail cars
- Large tree trunks (there is visual damage, but full cover is retained)
- Large obelisks in graveyards (there is visual damage, but full cover is retained)
- Terrain (anything soldiers can stand on)

Comment: btw cars can explode the turn they're hit if you do it with a grenade or rocket.

Comment: Large Tree Trunks can be destroyed.  A Tree seems to turn into a large tree trunk, and if that takes additional hits, it goes away.